# Use different encoding in const string

Tags: c++, linux, windows, encoding

I have a program that runs on linux and windows. This program receive data from linux/windows. Data is a Cyrillic strings. 
Program on linux receives data from windows and compare it with const vector with Cyrillic const fixed size strings. Or Program on Windows receives data from linux, and do same.

In linux fixed size string has 2 bytes per symbol, in windows 1 byte per symbol. 
The problem is how correctly compile this Cyrillic const strings to same encoding for Windows and Linux?

Comment: Working with Unicode in C++ is not easy without an external library. If all you do is compare strings, then why not just store everything in a `char32_t` string, aka `std::u32string` or `U"string"`. That way you can avoid the bytes per symbol mismatch.

Comment: @DeiDei It's good idea, but exists program which will be work with my program, and it is third party software. That software can send its locale to my program and no more. I know that this software use WCHAR_T(uint16_t) always and uses UTF-8 for linux and uses ISO-8859-5 for windows. And I don't know how solve it in future.